# find record by associated's model property

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm currently programming a Bug Tracker.

I have a table called `bug_states`. The revelant field is `closed` which is an `TINYINT` if it's set to 0 than this would say that the bug state marks the bug as unclosed (open). If it's set to 1 than this would say that the bug state marks the bug as closed.

Than I have a table called `milestones` it's structure isn't really relevant for this problem.

Than I have a last table called `bugs`. The revelant fields here are `bug_state_id` which is used by cakephp to create an association to the `bug_states` table and `milestone_id` which is used to associate the bug to a milestone.

Now I wan't to count how many bugs are open for a given milestone.

As Example, this is my code to get all bugs for a given milestone:

```
$total_bug_count = $this->Bug->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Bug.milestone_id' => $milestone_id)));
```

Does anyone know how I can count only the bugs which are open (that are those who have `BugState.closed = 0`)?

(If something is unclear, just say it ;-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was so simple (and I tried it so long...):

```
$this->Bug->find('count', array('conditions' => array('BugState.closed' => 0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to want to have a look at the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) behavior